# How can I output data from spreadsheet so it fits a single page for web publishing

Tags: excel, pdf, printing

I have a reporting program that generates a standard report for all regions. There are 16 regions and each contains many areas (typically between 60 and 250).  I would like to format this report in a manner that makes it easy to publish to the web.

Currently I format the report in Excel and print 16 PDFs (using vba). This works OK except that some of the regions have sufficient areas to warrant a second (or even third) page and this looks 'untidy'

If I define a special paper to the PDF printer then regions with a small number of areas have a lot of blank space at the bottom of the report

Is there some way I can output the information to a 'page' that is just long enough to hold all the information

Answer (score 0):

If the rows in your spreadsheet are of a standard height it would be easy to work out how many fit on a standard page then calculate the number of pages it should fit on and modify your code to use `.FitToPagesTall`

e.g.

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 3
End With
```

If the rows are of variable height, write some code to measure the accumulated height, then calculate the number of pages.

Finally, as implicitly the required print area must be changing dynamically you may want to add some code to fit the print area to the active data.

Comment: Hmmmm. Not, I think,  quite what I was looking for. If I understand correctly, FitToPagesTall = 3 will fit the report onto 3 pages whereas I want it to appear as 1 single page which is actually 3 pages long.

Comment: Then it shrinks the text so that it fits a standard A4 page and will thus have very small text. I want it on a page that is more than 1 A4 page lone and exactly 1 A4 page wide.

Comment: That's what it will do to fit it to one page.  You can squeeze down the margins and if the orientation is landscape change it to portrait. Beyond that you could fit to two pages and print as two-up with page 1 & 2 side-by-side.  I can't see how this can be done in Excel with "Save As..." format:=PDF; you might have to use a third party PDF maker like PrimoPDF which I know can do this.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go have a look at PrimoPDF